# I can't open database in XAMPP

Tags: php, database, xampp

Whenever I start XAMPP and start Apache and my SQL and click on the admin button on MySQL to make a new database it shows following error

> Fatal error: Maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded in C:\xampp\phpMyAdmin\libraries\dbi\DBIMysqli.class.php on line 290

Comment: try localhost/phpmyadmin in browser url

Comment: do you have large database in there or is this the first time you try opening it.

Comment: no i do not have a large database and its not the first time i am using it i used it day before yesterday created a database and i wanrted to add some tables to continue my work but it started showing off that error

Comment: I also tried that @Dhinju Divakaran

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this,

```
ini_set('max_execution_time', 120);
```

Otherwise goto `php ini` and look for `maxexecutiontime` and set it to 120 or whatever u need.

Comment: Not working saw this solution on stackoverflow itself

Comment: it's work for max_execution_time only

Comment: It worked manh thanx 120 dint do it i tried 1200 :D